# How do I write a rails migration to convert a field type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to convert a column from being :string to being :text non destructively.

Is there a straightforward method? It's PostgreSQL on Heroku.

Thanks!
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change_column` in another migration

- change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options): Changes the column to a different type using the same parameters as add_column.

Sourced from: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html & http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column